# Laravel big file upload not working, I get pending request

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload video files for my app, but the request is stuck on pending, and sometimes it shows invalid request (invalid eof) in terminal with php artisan serve. I have changed the following in php.ini, still nothing:

```
upload_max_filesize 2550M
post_max_size 50M
max_input_time 300
max_execution_time 300
```

UPDATE #1

React upload component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Button from "../../../Components/Button/Button";
import HttpClient from "../../../Services/HttpClient";

export default function () {
    const [file, setFile] = useState('');

    const onSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(file);

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('video', file);

        await HttpClient().post('/api/stream/upload', formData);
    }

    const handleChange = event => {
        setFile(event.target.files[0]);
    }

    return (
        <section className='pa-1'>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <input type='file' onChange={handleChange}/>
                <Button className='btn--primary' type='submit'>Upload</Button>
            </form>
        </section>
    )
}
```

StreamController.php

```
    public function upload(Request $request) {
        ini_set('post_max_size','2024M');
        ini_set('upload_max_filesize','2024M');
        $path = $request->file('video')->store('uploads');
        $video = new Video();
        $video->filename = $path;
        $video->save();
        return true;
    }
```

Anyone have a solution? It works with small files.

Comment: please show us the error in the terminal as i think it's not related with you php.ini file.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:51067 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)

Comment: `Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)` that means you have a syntax error in your code so double check your code again or share it with us.

Comment: updated with some code

Comment: So far so good, i don't see an error here that can cause you this problem, maybe you have done change somewhere else that may cause this issue. check laravel log file after running `php artisan serve` you will see something there sure.

Comment: how do i check the laravel log?

Comment: laravel logs file generally located at `storage/logs` named after each day date, but it's quite difficult to investigate with eyes, you can install "https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer" it's very helpful.

Comment: im still getting Invalid Request (Unexpected EOF). im trying to upload an .avi file 179MB big

Comment: i installed the package, but it doesnt show any relevant logs

Comment: when you open `/logs` url do you see any thing related `Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)` ?

Comment: no i dont. its empty

Comment: ok so heres the progress. i ran the laravel app using xampp, and it works. So I guess the problem is with php artisan serve

Comment: Ok that's great ! but you to find out what makes that error for you

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to your function. Then it must work

```
 ini_set('post_max_size','2024M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','2024M');
```

Comment: @user12912544 after change this did you restart apace/nginx?

Comment: im using laravel php artisan serve

Comment: Probably you can't change corrct php.ini file. Run this code and see your php.ini file location and change correct  php.ini file
<?php
phpinfo();
?>